# How to return a Reactive Flux that contains a Reactive Mono and Flux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm new to reactive programming and ran into this problem:

```
[
    {
        "customerDTO": {
            "scanAvailable": true
        },
        "bankAccountDTOs": {
            "scanAvailable": true,
            "prefetch": -1
        }
    }
]
```

DTO:

```
public class ResponseClientDTO {
    private Mono<CustomerDTO> customerDTO;
    private Flux<BankAccountDTO> bankAccountDTOs;
}
```

Service:

```
public Flux<ResponseClientDTO> getCustomerWithBankAccounts(String customerId){
    Flux<BankAccountDTO> bankAccounts = webClient
        .get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> 
                uriBuilder.path("customers")
                .queryParam("customerId", customerId).build())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(BankAccountDTO.class);
        
    
    Mono<CustomerDTO> cMono = findOne(customerId);
    
    ResponseClientDTO responseClientDTO = new ResponseClientDTO();
    responseClientDTO.setBankAccountDTOs(bankAccounts);
    responseClientDTO.setCustomerDTO(cMono);
    
    return Flux.just(responseClientDTO);
}
```

I query an endpoint from another API, and it returns a `Flux<BankAccounts>` . I want to get the client with all his bank accounts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not what you want in a reactive stack. First, change your DTO (Data Transfer Object) so that it does't include `Mono` and `Flux`, but `CustomerDTO` and `List<BankAccountDTO>` instead:

```java
public class ResponseClientDTO {
    private CustomerDTO customerDTO;
    private List<BankAccountDTO> bankAccountDTOs;
}
```

Then, you need to rearrange your method to return a `Mono<ResponseClientDTO>` instead and to change the logic to deal with `Flux` and `Mono`:

```java
public Mono<ResponseClientDTO> getCustomerWithBankAccounts(String customerId){
    Flux<BankAccountDTO> bankAccounts = webClient
        .get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> 
                uriBuilder.path("customers")
                .queryParam("customerId", customerId).build())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(BankAccountDTO.class);
        
    Mono<CustomerDTO> cMono = findOne(customerId);
    
    return bankAccounts.collectList().zipWith(cMono).map(data -> {
        ResponseClientDTO responseClientDTO = new ResponseClientDTO();
        responseClientDTO.setBankAccountDTOs(data.getT1());
        responseClientDTO.setCustomerDTO(data.getT2());
    })
}
```

*(Sorry for any Java typo but at this point I am too used to Kotlin).*

Consider taking a look at the following useful online resources:

- https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html
- https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html
- https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which-operator